# What is the meaning of 当たる here exactly?

Tags: meaning, words, nuances

In the vn rewrite, the protag こたろう is trying to salvage the relationship of two heroines ルチア and ちはや, together with 2 other heroines, 静流 and 小鳥. The protag thinks the following:

> 今回の作戦を立案したのは俺だ。とにかく、是が非でも仲直りを達成させ、今日を円満に終わらせなければならない。
> 小鳥や静流も十分、手伝ってくれてる。彼女らに当たるわけには行かない。

The english translation says that “I can’t rely on them”, but how does that meaning come forth? None of the jp definitions list a similar meaning in the dictionary, so I am troubled with remembering this use of 当たる. Could someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

If I guessed the context correctly, this 当たる is [the 12th definition here](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%BD%93%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B):

[image: 12. to treat (esp. harshly); to lash out at]

～に当たる in this sense refers to showing a cold or aggressive attitude toward someone (typically due to mental stress). You may have seen [八つ当たり](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%85%AB%E3%81%A4%E5%BD%93%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A) before. Does this fit the context?

Perhaps the English translator have mistaken it as [当てにする](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%BD%93%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B), but it's a completely different phrase.

**EDIT:** Maybe the protagonist is looking for someone to ask a favor or someone to work with? Then it's this:

> ##### [当たる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%BD%93%E3%82%8B/#:%7E:text=%EF%BC%94%20%E7%89%A9%E4%BA%8B%E3%81%AB%E6%8E%A2%E3%82%8A%E3%82%92%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%99%E3%82%92%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82%E7%A2%BA%E3%81%8B%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82%E3%80%8C%E5%8E%9F%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AB%E2%80%95%E3%83%BB%E3%82%8B%E3%80%8D%E3%80%8C%E4%BB%96%E3%81%AE%E5%BA%97%E3%82%92%E2%80%95%E3%83%BB%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%80%8D)
>
> ４ 物事に探りを入れる。ようすを見る。確かめてみる。「原本に―・る」「他の店を―・ってみよう」

> ##### [当たる](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%BD%93%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B)
>
> 17. to feel (something) out; to probe into; to check (i.e. by comparison)

> 二［他五］❶不明な点を明らかにしようとして、探りを入れる。また、調べ確かめる。
> 「その件は当局に当たってみよう」「問題の箇所を辞書に当たる」「胴回りの寸法を当たる」
> <sub>(Source: 大修館書店 明鏡国語辞典 第三版)</sub>

If this is the case, since the target is people, a literal translation would be "Sounding them out (if they can help) is not an option", but "I can't rely on them" is not bad, either.

Comment: I was also contemplating besides this meaning, as this fits in the best,  but in this context I don’t really see why the protag would 当たる at the other two heroines, as he isn’t really frustrated or anything. It is a possibility that the translator is wrong, throughout my playthrough of rewrite I have seen countless of awkward translations whenever I checked them, but in this situation I still cannot really see why the protag would 当たる at others, but yeah, meaning wise this is pretty much the only thing that makes sense here perhaps.

Comment: @Mernn1 See the edit.